# Laravel Deployment : PHP Error Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql'

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, webserver, postgresql-10

I want to deploy my laravel app in ubuntu server 18 LTS. So I have install nginx postgres php. But when i try to do `php artisan migrate` I have this returned error :

[This is the errror (a picture beacose of comande line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfDPG.jpg)
.

So I have verify different thing :
First I can access to my data base in localhost with the postgres user.
The laravel app work while database not be required.

In php.ini I have uncomment `extention=pdo-pgsql;` and `extention=pgsql`

I have install the php postgres sql extension with this command `sudo apt-get install php7.2-pgsql`

And this is my .env settings for database in laravel :

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5433
DB_DATABASE=THERY //I have already create the database
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=postgres
```

Comment: Try restarting the server or even the instance.

Comment: I have just try to reboot same and same error

Comment: Where is the database hosted?

Comment: On the same machine as the web server

Comment: Try `DB_HOST=localhost` instead of `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` in your .env.

Comment: I have try and same error

Comment: here is similar issue for mysql and a solution which worked https://askubuntu.com/questions/999999/php-with-pdo-mysql-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I have fixe the php error with your solution but I still have the SQLSTATE 08006 error

Comment: standard port for Postgres is 5432. Probably that is the case for "disconnects". Update your .env file and replace 5433 with 5432

Comment: YESSS IT WORK !!! Thanks realy
So simple but I don't have see this mistake
Post awser and I can acsept it then ^^

Comment: you can make an answer yourself and accept it. As a bonus you will master formatting of texts and get some new badges and reputation :-)

Comment: yes, I do that ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for my problem they have two solution plus a bonus

1. If the problem come from php and you don't want to reinstall all you can follow this topic [here in ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999999/php-with-pdo-mysql-in-ubuntu-16-04)
   and use this two command :

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove php-common

sudo apt-get install php-common php-pgsql php-cli
```

2. If you want to correctly install php for laravel with postgresql you can use this comandes:

```
#php install comande
sudo apt-get install php-fpm openssl php-common php-curl php-json php-mbstring php-xml php-zip php-pgsql

#make sure to uncomment extension=pdo_pgsql
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini 

#restart fpm service to apply settings
sudo systemctl restar php7.2-fpm
```

Finally if you have an [SQLSTATE 08006 error] check if the port in .env file in your laravel app correspond to the listened port in your server (form me the used port is 5432 and not 5433)

Answer (score 1):

There may be different issues for your problem. Any of the below may be occured:

1. php PGsql is not installed. install it by

```
apt-get install php-pgsql
```

2. PGsql library is missing in the composer. install it by

```
composer require asmiarowski/laravel-postgres // There are multiple librariies available in packagist
```

3. Your config in .env are not cached. you can cache them by running command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

4. Your PGSql server is not reachable. you can take further action to resolve them.

Comment: linux don't find php7.3-pgsql
It work if I use 7.2 ?

Comment: You can install "php-pgsql" or "php7.2-pgsql (if your PHP version is 7.2)" to use system reliable pgsql according to the installed PHP version. the answer was for representational purposes.

Comment: @MrSolarius What is your PHP version on CLI and on WebServer(Apache) ?

Comment: That have not work
I have this return error
`Unable to load dynamic library "pdo_pgsql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_pgsql (/usr/llb/php/20170718/pdo_pg /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_pgsql.so: undefined symbol: pdo parse_params)) in Unknown on line o PHP Warning: Module 'pgsql" already loaded in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: ````apt-get install php-pgsql```` should resolve the issue. can you paste a snapshot of phpinfo() page ?

Comment: I have verify now all module as here and no more error with psql but I still have the error SQLSTATE 08006